# Fabric JS multiple object selection ignores movement isDisabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I have set these following attributes to all of my objects on my Fabric JS canvas.

```
lockMovementX: isDisabled,
lockMovementY: isDisabled,
lockScalingX: isDisabled,
lockScalingY: isDisabled,
lockUniScaling: isDisabled,
lockRotation: isDisabled,
```

However, when I select multiple objects by holding the shift key, these objects get movable again, but as a group, any idea how I disable this possibility as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
canvas.selection = false
```

In this way, you can disable the group selection but the objects will still be selectable.

Comment: Hey I will try this, but it is best if they are still selectable, but just not movable.

Comment: Sure give it a try, and let me know if it is working correctly.

Comment: I tried it, it is ok, I still want to enable multiple object selection, I just want to disable its movements

Comment: take a look at this fiddle,https://jsfiddle.net/1whagL79/ whenever a selection is created it check if any object in selection has disabled movement it locks the movement of selection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the selectable property to false? That will prevent objects from being selected but events will still fire on them

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#selectable

> selectable :Boolean
> When set to `false`, an object can not be selected for modification (using either point-click-based or group-based selection). But events still fire on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I still want my objects to be selectable since I want to make some edits on them, just not moving them around.

Comment: You are setting all the editable properties to false so I assumed maybe you dont need to be able to select the object, can you explain what you are trying to achieve, since you are setting all the editable properties to false, what is exactly the need for object selection ?

Comment: Sure I am creating my own edit features that I want to be able to apply. So when a object is selected I still want the bounding box to be displayed. Basically the only feature I have is to change color on objects.

Comment: One thing you can do is to set canvas selection property to false, however that will prevent users to select multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering how many people do not understand a simple question.

Yes, it is possible. You have to listen to selection:updated and check if in the selection something is locked, then lock the target.

This worked for me with fabric 4.4.0. I cut it out from my project and hope this code example work. At least it should demonstrate the “how”.

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

isLockedInSelection()
{
    let activeObjects = canvas.getActiveObjects();
    for (let i in activeObjects)
    {
        if (activeObjects[i].lockMovementX)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

canvas.on('selection:updated', ({selected, target}) =>
{
    if (isLockedInSelection())
    {
        target.lockMovementX = true;
        target.lockMovementY = true;
        target.lockSkewingX  = true;
        target.lockSkewingY  = true;
        target.lockRotation  = true;
        target.lockScalingX  = true;
        target.lockScalingY  = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, it is possible. You have to listen to selection:updated and check if in the selection something is locked, then lock the target.

Appreciate this approach and I may need it at some point down the road. For my own current implementation I chose to simply deselect any locked objects

```js
function objectIsLocked(object) {
  return (
    object.lockMovementX &&
    object.lockMovementY &&
    object.lockRotation &&
    object.lockScalingFlip &&
    object.lockScalingX &&
    object.lockScalingY &&
    object.lockSkewingX &&
    object.lockSkewingY
  )
}

canvas.on('selection:created', (e) => {
    let dirty = false
    e.selected.forEach((obj) => {
      if (objectIsLocked(obj)) {
        canvas.getActiveObject().removeWithUpdate(obj)
        dirty = true
      }
    })

    if (dirty) this.canvas.requestRenderAll()
})
```